# Android OS12 Pixel Device RSA issue

Tags: android, jwt, rsa

Hey guy's i have an app that im doing that uses encryption and JWT.

i test on my pixel 5 OS12 device and have no issue. I just tested on my new Pixel 6 Pro and i get a bad padding exception?

javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: error:04000089:RSA routines:OPENSSL_internal:PKCS_DECODING_ERROR

the device sends a base64 string i need to decode it then decrypt RSA with my private key

```
val decoded = android.util.Base64.decode(full, android.util.Base64.NO_WRAP)

fun decryptByPrivateKey3(encryptedData: ByteArray?): ByteArray? {
    val privateKey = getKeyFromString()
    return try {
        val cipher1: Cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding")
        cipher1.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey)
        cipher1.doFinal(encryptedData)
    } catch (e: java.lang.Exception) {
        Timber.d("Error Decrypting Key $e")
        null
    }
}
```

its odd cause it is standard code..if i remove the RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding it passes but causes an issue on my Signing of a JWT .(Since that is the secret message)

any body have issues with this on different phones?

Comment: Have you verified that `privateKey` and `encryptedData` are identical in both cases?

Comment: the encrypted data is received as base64 decode then decrypt with RSA and private key. on my pixel 5 no issues works like a charm but on other devices like my pixel6 pro and even samsung s9 i get a bad padding exception. the device signes it with the rsa public and i decrypt with private rsa key from the same keypair as the device

Comment: Can you post a sample private key and ciphertext that works on the one device and not on the other? And also the implementation of `getKeyFromString()`.

Comment: Actually you were right.i guess the keys change per device..cause using my pixel is always the same key. i check my database and it wasnt the same at all..tested and it worked.thx!

Answer (score 0):

Seems that using one phone had always the same keys. When i used another phone the keys changed.The RSA was hardcoded to test.